# Setting up static files in Django

Tags: python, django, file, static

I have problems with setting up static files in my Django project on development server. I'm using Django-1.6.1 with Python 2.7.5+.

I followed the instrucions from this link:
[Managing static files (CSS, images)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

So, i added **django.contrib.staticfiles** into INSTALLED_APPS

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'BlogContent',
)
```

I set up **STATIC_URL**:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And i also modify my urls.py to this:

```py
urlpatterns = [           
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', home_view ),
    url(r'^about/$', about_view )
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In template i use this tag:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "elo.jpg" %}"/>
```

And all files are into project_root/static/ and after run server i recieve this:

```
"GET /static/elo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1625
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve it ? Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web server you choose.
so remove `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in `urls.py`. Use Apache2 to store your static or media files

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

In your Apache `*.conf` file(Apache 2.4)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin example@example.com

        Alias /media/ /home/tu/blog/media/
        Alias /static/ /home/tu/blog/collected_static/

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/collected_static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tu/blog/blog/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/tu/blog/blog>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you use Apache 2.2 use

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

instead of

```
Require all granted
```

Note: You can run `apachectl -v` to see your Apache2 version

Comment: if just one website, you can remove `<VirtualHost>` label

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am using a ProxyPass and have set `ProxyPass /static/ !` for static files, still getting a 403.

Comment: @varagrawal you could put `Alias /static/ /path/to/static` before other `ProxyPass / host:8000`

Answer (score 0):

And here is a spinet of a [nginx](http://nginx.org/) configuration to serve static files & proxy to the application called APP:

```
http {
…
    server {
        …
        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
        }

        location /APP {
            return 301 /APP/;
        }

        location /APP/ {
            rewrite ^/intranet(.*) /$1 break; 
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I use [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) to run my app on `localhost:8000` but I connect to it using `http://localhost/APP`.